# Different Execution Times for separate runs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am creating a utility that is going to be used to benchmark different duplicate finding algorithms. To accurately determine execution time, I used an example that I got from [here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.cpp/2004-03/1376.html). It's basically a function that returns the amount of CPU ticks that has elapsed since CPU startup. I am no expert on assembly so I assume/hope the code example is correct.

This is what my main function looks like.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    // The size of the array that is going to be tested.
    int Size = 1000000;    
    int * Array = GenerateRandomArray(Size);

    // take a time measurement before.
    __int64 TicksBefore = GetCpuClocks();

    // Insert algorithm to benchmark here.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {};

    // take a time measurement afterwords.
    __int64 TicksAfter = GetCpuClocks();

    // calculate the amount of ticks that has passed.
    __int64 TicksElapsed = TicksAfter - TicksBefore;

    cout << "\nThe amount of ticks that has elapsed for this operation is: " << TicksElapsed << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

My question, purely out of curiosity, is why does the elapsed time differ between runs? If I run this as-is on my machine I get times between 850 and 900, always in multiples of 10. If I remove the `GenerateRandomArray(Size)` line then the amount of time elapsed *increases* to between 1010 and 1200! This is not a train smash for me. The distribution is small enough for me that I can still extract valuable data from it.

I am just really curious why this happens. Does the state of the stack/heap have an effect or is it just interrupts that occur in the system that is beyond my control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Any tick-level benchmarking is extremely sensitive to cache state on modern processors** (including TLB, branch predictors, etc. too!). To get consistent results, you should run your tested logic a few time, take t0, run the logic thousands if not millions of times, then take t1, substract, and divide.

Hitting main memory once can cost ~100 cycles on a 3 GHz CPU, and missing a TLB virtual address translation, etc., can hit main memory 3 or 4 times! Your large memory allocation may be forcing the underlying C/C++ runtime library to request more virtual address space from the OS via a system call, which would result in two mode switches and filling some of the cache with OS logic and data. **You need to isolate what you want tested, "warm" your cache, and take large aggregate measurements to get anything meaningful.**

Something else to note is that modern superscalar, "out-of-order" CPUs have a very loose notion of "when" an operation happens in terms of clocks. A dozen operations may be pending any any given time in varying states of completeness, and sometimes state will be rolled back a dozen clock cycles because of a mispredicted branch or a speculative memory read that turned out to be invalidated by a write by another core. Instructions can be broadly reordered, and the default `RDTSC` instruction to get the cycle count is vulnerable to this. The newer `RDTSCP` instruction is serialized, meaning that its order is enforced, but this can actually cost the CPU a few cycles of productivity to be able to draw a clear line of what goes before and after this instruction.

Comment: I suspected as such. Thanks! Your mention about `RDTSCP` put me on the track to reading Intel's white paper on performance measurement. I will implement what is noted there and see if I get more consistent results.